# Is the below use of outer join correct as the data doesn't fetch correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, join, inner-join, outer-join

Hi I have the below data in the table 
[Exsiting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4EsJ.png)
With the below query I only get the common vouchers
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCCJh.png)

However i need also the row which doesn't not have the voucher that has a corresponding -ve (it basically is voucher sold and voucher redeemed.)

So only 1 voucher was sold and redeemed and one is yet to be redeemed.
How do i recover the row that is not yet redeemed.

```
SELECT t1.STORE,
       t1.DAY,
       t1.tran_seq_no,
       t2.tran_seq_no,
       t2.DAY,
       t1.tender_amt,
       t2.tender_amt,
       t1.voucher_no,
       t2.voucher_no 
FROM   sa_tran_tender t1,
       sa_tran_tender t2
where  t1.voucher_no(+)=t2.voucher_no
AND    t1.DAY=4
AND    t1.tender_amt<0
AND    t1.tender_type_group ='VOUCH' 
AND    t2.tender_amt>0
AND    t1.STORE=400112
AND    t1.tran_seq_no       IN(2632729010,2632729056,3140772029)
AND    t1.STORE(+)=t2.STORE
and    t1.tender_type_group(+)=t2.tender_type_group;
```

Comment: The modern `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` syntax is (for most people) clearer and less prone to mistakes, maybe try it?

Comment: Maybe decide on an upper/lower case strategy and stick to it. The code above gives me a migraine ;)

Comment: Oracle recommends to stop using the `(+)` operator and use the explicit `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there will be a single voucher sale (with negative `tender_amt`) and then a single optional redemption of the voucher (with positive `tender_amt` and a later `tran_seq_no`) then you don't need to use a self join; instead you can use the `LAG` or `LEAD` analytic functions (and will only require a single table scan compared to the two table scans for a self join):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73d91/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE sa_tran_tender ( store, day, tran_seq_no, voucher_no, tender_amt, tender_type_group ) AS
SELECT 400112, 4, 2632729010, '400112*101*21090', -39.95, 'VOUCH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400112, 4, 2632729056, '400112*101*21136',  -6.99, 'VOUCH' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 400112, 5, 3140772029, '400112*101*21090',  39.95, 'VOUCH' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD( DAY )         OVER ( PARTITION BY voucher_no, store, tender_type_group ORDER BY tran_seq_no ) AS redeemed_day,
         LEAD( tender_amt )  OVER ( PARTITION BY voucher_no, store, tender_type_group ORDER BY tran_seq_no ) AS redeemed_amt,
         LEAD( tran_seq_no ) OVER ( PARTITION BY voucher_no, store, tender_type_group ORDER BY tran_seq_no ) AS redeemed_tran_seq_no
  FROM   sa_tran_tender t
)
WHERE  tran_seq_no       IN( 2632729010, 2632729056, 3140772029)
AND    tender_type_group ='VOUCH' 
AND    STORE             =400112
AND    DAY               =4
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73d91/2/0)**:

```
|  STORE | DAY | TRAN_SEQ_NO |       VOUCHER_NO | TENDER_AMT | TENDER_TYPE_GROUP | REDEEMED_DAY | REDEEMED_AMT | REDEEMED_TRAN_SEQ_NO |
|--------|-----|-------------|------------------|------------|-------------------|--------------|--------------|----------------------|
| 400112 |   4 |  2632729010 | 400112*101*21090 |     -39.95 |             VOUCH |            5 |        39.95 |           3140772029 |
| 400112 |   4 |  2632729056 | 400112*101*21136 |      -6.99 |             VOUCH |       (null) |       (null) |               (null) |
```

However, if you do want to use an (inefficient) self-join then you could do:

```
SELECT t1.STORE,
       t1.DAY,
       t1.tran_seq_no,
       t2.tran_seq_no,
       t2.DAY,
       t1.tender_amt,
       t2.tender_amt,
       t1.voucher_no,
       t2.voucher_no 
FROM   sa_tran_tender t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       sa_tran_tender t2
       ON (    t1.voucher_no        = t2.voucher_no
           AND t2.tender_amt        > 0
           AND t1.store             = t2.store
           AND t1.tender_type_group = t2.tender_type_group )
WHERE  t1.DAY               = 4
AND    t1.tender_amt        < 0
AND    t1.tender_type_group = 'VOUCH' 
AND    t1.STORE             = 400112
AND    t1.tran_seq_no       IN (2632729010,2632729056,3140772029);
```

Comment: Hi @MT0, Thank you very much for the above methods. The second one worked perfectly. Whereas the above method using LEAD Function, doesnt display the redemmed voucher and other details. All other Columns(redeemed_day,redeemed_amt,redeemed_tran_seq_no) are null for both the vouchers whereas it has to be null only for the one that is not redemmed...

Answer (score 1):

When you use oracle joun syntax you should to add `(+)` to every field in `WHERE` condtition of left-joined table (not for only connected fields with another table) -

```
where  t1.voucher_no(+)=t2.voucher_no
AND    t1.DAY=4(+)
AND    t1.tender_amt(+)<0
AND    t1.tender_type_group(+) ='VOUCH' 
AND    t2.tender_amt>0
AND    t1.STORE(+)=400112
AND    t1.tran_seq_no(+) IN(2632729010,2632729056,3140772029)
AND    t1.STORE(+)=t2.STORE
and    t1.tender_type_group(+)=t2.tender_type_group
```

or you can use ANSI-joins.